# Trying to inject a cross-domain iframe into a webview using react native

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, webview, react-native

I'm using the webview component of react native to open "https://google.com", i'm also using the injectedJavascript prop of the webview to inject a script that adds an iframe and set it's src to the secure url for 'yahoo.com'.  The iframe is created but the contents of the iframe are not shown (See the two image urls below)

If I use 'https://google.com' instead of 'yahoo.com', the iframe displays the contents of the page. I'm guessing any iframe that does not share the parent windows domain will not show up. This is different then the experience on the chrome browser on my desktop, where I 'can' inject an iframe and set it's source to be different then the parent and have the cross-domain iframe show up.

I was wondering if there is a way to inject an iframe without the same domain as the parent in webbview and have it show it's contents. If not, is there a workaround that can have communication with a page on the webview and a different domain? I was hoping to eventually use window.postMessage to accomplish this, but it sounds like this isn't possible with the 'possible' security protections in an ios webview?

[parent window is google , iframe with src = yahoo,...
i.stack.imgur.com/tRGps.png

[parent window is google, iframe with src = google,...
i.stack.imgur.com/H9fU9.png

Comment: ended up working around this issue, using react-native-webview-bridge.  Tutorial here, http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/25/send-receive-data-between-react-native-and-webview.html.

Comment: so instead of using window.postMessage to send data between the parent window and a nested frame with a different domain, I instead send the data back to the reactNative app using react-native-webview-bridge.